# Passing a variable as an attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

```
list=[ 'attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3']
for x in list:
  foo = bar.x ()

Error:
AttributeError: module 'bar' has no attribute 'x'
```

**bar** has all attributes but I don't know how to pass the variable as an attribute, there should be a way to do **bar.attribute1 bar.attribute2 bar.attribute3** without literally specifying it

the solution:

```
list=[ 'attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3']
for x in list:
  foo = bar
  foo = getattr(foo, x) ()
```

Comment: You cannot "pass a variable as an attribute". You can pass a *string* that can be used to dynamically access attirbutes using `getattr`.

Comment: Note, you *could* have done something like `exec(f"foo = bar.{x}()")` but this is hacky and brittle (behaves differently in local vs global namespaces..., if you want to make it more resiliant you have to take care with the arguments you pass to exec). Use `foo = getattr(bar, x)()` instead